# How to remove a Controller from the router backstack in Conductor?

Tags: android, conductor, android-mvp

I'm using [Conductor](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor) and Mosby to implement MVP-MVC architecture in an android app.
What I need to do is remove a Controller from the backstack of a router so that upon `onBackPressed` that controller is no longer brought back up to the front.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Just pop the backstack? Then call `router.popCurrentController()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove current controller, do like @sockeqwe said: call `router.popCurrentController()`.

If you want to remove some specific controller from the backstack, you could try calling `router.popController(your_controller)`.